# Pandas - add value to series indicating the first time each value in one series appears in each year

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

| Date/time | File |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 09:00:00 | File A |
| 2021-02-01 09:00:00 | File A |
| 2022-01-01 09:00:00 | File A |
| 2021-01-01 09:00:00 | File B |
| 2022-01-01 09:00:00 | File B |
| 2022-01-01 09:00:00 | File C |
| 2022-02-01 09:00:00 | File C |
| 2022-02-01 10:00:00 | File C |

What I am trying to do, is add a column for 'First occurrence' where each File is marked with a 1 for the first time it appears in each year

So the desired output would be:

| Date/time | File | First occurrence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 09:00:00 | File A | 1 |
| 2021-02-01 09:00:00 | File A |  |
| 2022-01-01 09:00:00 | File A | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 09:00:00 | File B | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 09:00:00 | File B | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 09:00:00 | File C | 1 |
| 2022-02-01 09:00:00 | File C |  |
| 2022-02-01 10:00:00 | File C |  |

What I've tried so far which works:

```
df= df.sort_values(["File", "Date/time"])
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df["First occurrence"] = df.groupby(["File"]).cumcount() 
df["First occurrence"] = np.where(df["First scan"] == 0, 1, 0)
```

This works at the first occurrence for each file, but doesn't work for each year. Building on that, I tried groupby methods and couldn't get it working so I went with a brute force approach which is:

```
# Get list of years
year_list = df["Date/time"].dt.year.unique().tolist()

year_frames = []
for year in year_list:
    yr_df = df[df["Date/time"].dt.year==year]
    yr_df = yr_df.sort_values(["File", "Date/time"])
    yr_df = yr_df.reset_index(drop=True)

    yr_df["First scan"] = yr_df.groupby(["File"]).cumcount() 
    yr_df["First scan"] = np.where(yr_df["First scan"] == 0, 1, 0)
    
    year_frames.append(yr_df) 

final_df = pd.concat(year_frames, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

This works for each year df but the concat overwrites values of 1 and 0 as the two frames are joined.

I'd like to get better with Pandas so would rather not brute force it in this way if there's a suitable way to do it but so far hours worth of Googling hasn't give me much to go on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `year` column and use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to check the duplicated item in `year` and `File` columns

```py
df['Date/time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/time'])
df['year'] = df['Date/time'].dt.year
df['First occurrence'] = (~df.duplicated(['year', 'File'])).astype(int)
```

```
print(df)

            Date/time    File  year  First occurrence
0 2021-01-01 09:00:00  File A  2021                 1
1 2021-02-01 09:00:00  File A  2021                 0
2 2022-01-01 09:00:00  File A  2022                 1
3 2021-01-01 09:00:00  File B  2021                 1
4 2022-01-01 09:00:00  File B  2022                 1
5 2022-01-01 09:00:00  File C  2022                 1
6 2022-02-01 09:00:00  File C  2022                 0
7 2022-02-01 10:00:00  File C  2022                 0
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I always feel that it'll be complicated with Pandas, but there's seems to usually be some elegant way of doing it, like this.

Time to hit some more tutorials!